# For loops in a dictionary and if statement

Tags: python, loops, if-statement, for-loop, dictionary

Firstly, I have to say that i'm a beginner in python.
Then, here is my problem :
I have a dictionary like this one :

```
dic = {} 
dic["a", 1] = 0 
dic["a", 2] = 2 
dic["b", 1] = 5 
dic["b", 2] = 0 
...
```

And I want to do a for-loop with this dictionary to test all the keys' pair and find which ones are equivalent to 0 in a if statement.
I thought of that :

```
for [co, l], ch in dic.items(): 
    if [co, l] == 0:
```

But the if statement is never true, so I can't do anything.
Does anyone could provide me some help, please ?

Thanks

Comment: You forgot to use `dic` before `[co, l]`.

Comment: Why are you testing `[co, l]` for equality to 0? You want to test the value, `ch`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`[co, l]` is the key (or copy of it); it is a list with 2 items, and cannot be equal to 0. Instead you want to test the `ch` value and then perhaps do something with the key.

```
dic = {} 
dic["a", 1] = 0 
dic["a", 2] = 2 
dic["b", 1] = 5 
dic["b", 2] = 0 
... 

for [co, l], ch in dic.items(): 
    if ch == 0:
        print("The value for key {}, {} was 0".format(co, l))
```

Or if you want to iterate by the key:

```
for key in dic:
    if dic[key] == 0:
        print("The value for key {} was 0".format(key))
```

Answer (score 0):

As per the comments:

```
for ch in dic.items():
    if ch == 0:
```

Comment: Please provide a better description so that the OP and future visitors to SO will understand what you have done.

Answer (score 0):

[co, l] is never 0.  I think you mean to test ch.

```
for [co, l], ch in dic.items():
...     print [co, l], ch
...
['a', 1] 0
['b', 2] 0
['b', 1] 5
['a', 2] 2
```